# JavaScript - Loop through Images and stop the execution at the last Image

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, shopify

I have a object with images. Right now my code loops through the images and shows one image every 3 seconds. I was wondering if I can stop the exaction in the last image that is located in a object.

```
var myImages = {{ image_frame_hotspot }};
    
    if(myImages) {
        for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(myImages)) {
            $('#images').append("<img class=\"slides slides-hidden\" src=\"" + value + "\"/>")
        }
    }
```

The first code is how I get the object with liquid tags that is used in Shopify, then I use append to show them in a img tag.

```
addEventListener("load",() => {
    var index = 0;
    const slides = document.querySelectorAll(".slides");
    const classHide = "slides-hidden", count = slides.length;
    nextSlide();
    function nextSlide() {
        slides[(index ++) % count].classList.add(classHide);
        slides[index % count].classList.remove(classHide);
        setTimeout(nextSlide, 3000);
    }
});
```

Right know this code loops throught all the images and uses class "slides-hidden"
to hide all images and show only one every 3 seconds. I am trying to stop the execution at the last image that way I can get a frame by frame image animation.

Comment: Stop execution of 'nextSlide'  do you mean ? I guess you could add a condition like ` if ( index < slides.length -1 . That way the last slide won't be taken into consideration

Comment: Inside your nextSlide() - `if (index>count) return` (or maybe `if (++index > count)` - or just `index++` first and don't put it inside an if / % as that's so much clearer.

Comment: Both comments works thanks a lot.